# How can I have a foreign key to a HasAndBelongsToMany table and still perform valid find query in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have these tables in my database, with their corresponding models in cakephp:

Table `topics` :
- `id`
- `name`

Table `academics`:
- `id`
- `full_name`

Table `academics_topics` (many topics can be taught by many instructors):
- `id`
- `academic_id`
- `topic_id`

Table `topicschedules` (each topic that is taught by a specific instructor has many schedules):
- `id`
- `academic_topic_id`
- `date_from`
- `date_to`
- `time_from`
- `time_to`

There will also be table for grades that is related to a specific `academic_topic_id`

The correct database relations are setup for each.

The `topicschedules` has the following relation: $belongsTo = 'AcademicsTopic';

The AcademicsTopic model has a virtual field AcademicsTopic.name : Academic.name concatinated with Topic.name

What i want is that when I call the find method on my topicschedules, I want the virtual field AcademicsTopic.name to also be returned with the result. Is there any "cake-ish" way of achieving that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

```
$this->TopicSchedule->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'AcademicsTopic' => array(
            'fields' => array('name')
        )
    )
);
```